# Planck distribution integration

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, photometry

Does anyone know how to compute analytically or numerically the following integral (for $T=10^4$K)?:

$$n_\gamma=\frac{1}{\hbar^3\pi^2c^3}\int\limits_{2.1789\cdot 10^{-18}}^{+\infty}\dfrac{E^2\mathrm{d}E}{e^{\frac{E}{kT}}-1}$$

I tried with R, MATLAB, Maxima, Maple and Wolfram but I failed. I also search an analytical solution during a least a whole week....

Thx in advance for your help.

Comment: What are the units of $2.1789\cdot 10^{-18}$?

Comment: What does “I failed” mean? What prevented you from obtaining a numerical integration?

Comment: Why is the lower limit not zero? Photons of arbitrarily low energy contribute to the number density.

Comment: @G.Smith The units are [J] ( the equivalent of 13.6 [eV])

Comment: @G.Smith "i failed" mean that with all my softwares the convergence seems to fail.

Comment: @G.SmithThe lower limit is not zero because we are interested only on photons that have an energy higher that the first level of ionization of the Hydrogen atom (13.6 eV)

Comment: How could the convergence fail when the integrand becomes exponentially small as $E\to\infty$?

Comment: @G.Smith I wrote "seems to fail" and not just "fail". The point is something cause a problem (whatever it is: very likely because of my ignorance).

Comment: You are probably having trouble because you didn’t de-dimensionalize the integral.

Comment: I had no trouble evaluating the integral numerically after de- dimensionalizing it.

Comment: If I didn’t de-dimensionalize, I had to use the option Method->”DoubleExponential” with NIntegrate[] in *Mathematica*. Otherwise, I got $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes computers have issues dealing with precision. Also try a change of variables like u=E/kT. Then factor out all the constants. So you get something like u^2du/(e^u-1) in your integral. This will simplify things in your numerical calculation. Once you calculate this integral, then you can just multiply back in the constants at the end.

Comment: *This 2.1789⋅10−18 is essentially zero, so you can make that assumption.* You cannot assume the lower limit is zero. If you change variables to $x$, you will find out how very different from zero the lower limit is.

Comment: True, although I feel that won't be the biggest issue. Rescaling some of the variables may help though.

Comment: I have done the calculation, both by rescaling and not. If you set the lower limit to zero you will be wrong by about five orders of magnitude. Your statement “you can make that assumption” is false.

Comment: I just checked the lower limit is of similar order to kT, so you are correct we cannot assume it is zero. I will edit my response accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I’ve upvoted.

Comment: @Ali Ok i will try and let you know if it works or not.

Comment: @Ali Ok it worked! Thx you had a nice and simple idea.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, one just need to do a little work before the analytic software can handle the integration. Here is a suggestion. First write it in the form:
$$ \frac{A}{\exp(Bx)-1}=\frac{A\exp(-Bx)}{1-\exp(-Bx)} . $$
Then expand the denominator
$$ \frac{A\exp(-Bx)}{1-\exp(-Bx)} = A\exp(-Bx)\sum_n \exp(-nBx) . $$
Now you (or Maple, etc.) should be able to integrate every term after which you can resum the series.

Comment: Although one can expand the integrand in a series, it isn’t necessary to do that.